# Excel - Temporary Filter Views - How to detect if a cell has exactly 2 or more string values

Tags: excel

For example I have this in my cells:

| Name |
| --- |
| Smith, John |
| Miller, James David |
| Johnson, George Anthony Montana |
| Williams, Andrew |

How can I have my temporary filtered view to show only 2 exact strings from a cell? The output should be like this:

| Name |
| --- |
| Smith, John |
| Williams, Andrew |

Likewise what if I only want to show only this:

| Name |
| --- |
| Miller, James David |

Or this:

| Name |
| --- |
| Johnson, George Anthony Montana |

Does it have something to do with the "Text is exactly" formula? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Count the number of spaces. then use an if(). But you might need to trap leading and trailing spaces - those who enter data add spaces by accident or design...

Comment: are you talking of using "sheet view"?

Answer (score 0):

So, try this, I have left it in separate cells:

[image]

Copies of the 3 formulae used, just to save you typing:

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))

=IF(C2=1,A2,"")

=UNIQUE(D2:D5,,1)
```

I have not added trim() but you can.

```
=LEN(trim(A2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(trim(A2)," ",""))
```

However, I would control the source data to not need this.

To show other results, change the 1 in the if(c2=1, to 2 or <3 as needed. I would put that in an external cell so it becomes easy to change:

```
IF(C2=F2,A2,"")
```

Where F2 contains a 1 or 2 or what is needed.

Comment: =FILTER(D2:D5,D2:D5<>"") instead of =UNIQUE(D2:D5,,1) wouldn't show blank in that one scenario when only 1 row is to be filtered out and wouldn't remove duplicates (completely) (if it is not what OP is looking for)

Comment: @user11222393 will try that, thanks. there is always more than one way...

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(y,BYROW(A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,IF(COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(x)," "))=2,x,""))),FILTER(y,y<>""))
```

where 2 in the end of `COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(x)," "))=2` is parameter to how many "words" to filter.

Drawback it doesn't apply filter to your data, but creates new table with altered data.

Result:

[image]